# here map fragment embed with the another fragment layout

Tags: android

Is it possible to embed the here map fragment with another fragment layout and perform business logic functions on the child map fragment. If any snippets much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding the Map Fragment on runtime to the required fragment layout as mentioned in documentation https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/dynamic-mapfragment.html

Comment: The Map Fragment during runtime it's helpful on Activity. My problem is different. Consider MainActivity has setContentview with layout here it contains  FrameLayout as container. This container is replaced with Frag1, Frag2, Frag3 on Menu item click.  Here fragment are replaced successfully with different layouts by inflater. Similarly I want to replace the MapFragment as a layout. In fragment layout I can't declare the <fragment class="com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment1" android:id="@+id/mapfragment" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>  so now?

Comment: My question is how to add Map Fragment  with fragment layout?